# Heroku : Support of InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, heroku

Does Heroku supports MySQL (esp. InnoDB database engine) ?

I see there is ClearDB add-on, but it didn't state it supports InnoDB or not.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Comment: Also, one of the add-ons they provide is Amazon RDS, which definitely supports InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku itself only provides direct support for PostgreSQL. Many applications (especially those in Rails) can be [migrated from MySQL to PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql) with little issue.

For situations in which you can't easily migrate, you can [use a third party Heroku add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/?q=mysql).